# docker tkinter create_text segmentation fault

Tags: python, docker, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am creating a tool that allows the user to manipulate graphs through a GUI. To help with the graph manipulation, [I am using this library through Docker.](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) The issue is that when I try to use `create_text`, through tkinter version 8.5 with Python 3.6, I am getting the error `Segmentation fault`. I am using X11 forwarding and `create_line` and other functions like that do work, so I am not sure how to debug this.

The code I use to replicate this error:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, height=650, bg = '#afeeee')
canvas.create_text(0,0)
root.mainloop()
```

Even when no options are provided to create_text, I still get the segfault.

Comment: Use `journalctl -n 10 -f` and then run your container. See if you find anything interesting in logs?

Comment: I'm on OS X and I get "-bash: journalctl: command not found". My container has journalctl, however, it says "No journal files were found." and then waits seemingly forever. I looked under `/var/log` for any logs but could not find any that were related to my issue.

Comment: Share your complete config, Dockerfile, compose files if any

Comment: I don't have access to the Dockerfile (or those other things which I don't really know), as I pulled it already completed from:
https://hub.docker.com/r/tiagopeixoto/graph-tool/